# How to use BitsTransfer to download a file from a remote host with domain authentication

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to be able to download a file from a server (running windows Server 2008 r2) to my client windows 10 computer over a network that uses domain authentication (I will need to provide credentials to the server).

I need to do this using powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fully documented in the Microsoft provided docs and help files and all over the web.

[Using Windows PowerShell to Create BITS Transfer Jobs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/using-windows-powershell-to-create-bits-transfer-jobs)

[Leverage BITS for File Transfers with PowerShell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/08/03/leverage-bits-for-file-transfers-with-powershell.aspx)

All-in-all, just use the BITS cmdlets and just use the help files, and their provided examples in them:

```
Get-Command -Name '*bits*'

CommandType Name                   Version     Source                           
----------- ----                   -------     ------                           
Cmdlet      Add-BitsFile           2.0.0.0     BitsTransfer                     
Cmdlet      Complete-BitsTransfer  2.0.0.0     BitsTransfer                     
Cmdlet      Get-BitsTransfer       2.0.0.0     BitsTransfer                     
Cmdlet      Remove-BitsTransfer    2.0.0.0     BitsTransfer                     
Cmdlet      Resume-BitsTransfer    2.0.0.0     BitsTransfer                     
Cmdlet      Set-BitsTransfer       2.0.0.0     BitsTransfer                     
Cmdlet      Start-BitsTransfer     2.0.0.0     BitsTransfer                     
Cmdlet      Suspend-BitsTransfer   2.0.0.0     BitsTransfer                     
Application bitsadmin.exe          7.8.17763.1 C:\Windows\system32\bitsadmin.exe


# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADUser).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-ADUser -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ADUser -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ADUser -Online


Get-Help about_*
Get-Help about_Functions


# All Help topics locations
Get-Help about* | Select Name, Synopsis

Get-Help about* | 
  Select-Object -Property Name, Synopsis |
  Out-GridView -Title 'Select Topic' -OutputMode Multiple |
  ForEach-Object {
    Get-Help -Name $_.Name -ShowWindow
  }

explorer "$pshome\$($Host.CurrentCulture.Name)"
```

Comment: After better analysis, i have revised my question: https://superuser.com/questions/1382403/start-bitstransfer-cannot-find-path-because-it-does-not-exist-with-diffe

Comment: yeah I want to delete it but it tells me I can't because others have already spent time on answering it

Comment: I guess this answer sounds correct enough though