# Start-BitsTransfer - "Cannot find path ... because it does not exist" with different credentials to local host

Tags: windows, powershell

I am typing the following command in a PowerShell prompt:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "\\serverA\c$\test.txt" -Destination . -TransferType Download -cred (get-credential)
```

After typing the credentials correctly, I get:

> Cannot find path "\\serverA\c$\test.txt" because it does not exist

I can map \\serverA\c$ to a network drive (e.g. Y:\) and then the following works:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "Y:\\test.txt" -Destination . -TransferType Download
```

But this is not desirable because I need the capability to be able to download files from more than 26 servers at a time, which means I'll run out of drive letters.

Comment: Can you run the command in the context of a user account that *already* has permission to the remote `C$` share?

Comment: It may be more straightforward to perform this transfer from the other direction instead, running it on the destination machines.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Unfortunately the users won't have access to such an account.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Due to a complex (corporate) network topology, I don't think this'll be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The New-PSDrive command can create temporary drive mappings within the shell which can be named as any string. Since I do not need these drives to persist, this is a good solution for me, and the -Credential parameter is not bugged (like it is with start-bitstransfer).

```
New-PSDrive -name "drive1" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\serverA\c$" -cred $cred
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "drive1:\\test.txt" -Destination .
```

This works fine and there's no (unreasonable) limit to the number of temporary drive mappings you can create. For more info about New-PSDrive, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-6